# No trainable parameters when implementing Fourier convolution in Keras layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, convolution

I'm attempting to implement a Fourier Convolutional Neural Network using tf.keras, where the input and kernel are transformed to the frequency domain, element-wise multiplication is performed, and then the output is inverse-transformed and cropped. The model summary shows there are no trainable parameters for the kernel in my FConv2D layer, even though I declare them using `self.add_weight`. There should be (3*3*in_channels*no_of_kernels) parameters.

```
class FConv2D(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, no_of_kernels, **kwargs):
        self.no_of_kernels = no_of_kernels
        super(FConv2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel_shape = (3, 3 , int(input_shape[3]), self.no_of_kernels)
        print(input_shape, self.kernel_shape)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(3,3, input_shape[-1], self.no_of_kernels),
                             initializer='random_normal',
                             trainable=True)
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.no_of_kernels,),
                             initializer='random_normal',
                             trainable=True)
        super(FConv2D, self).build(input_shape)


    def call(self, x):
        crop_size = self.kernel.get_shape().as_list()[0] // 2
        shape = x.get_shape().as_list()[1] + self.kernel.get_shape().as_list()[0] - 1
        x = tf.transpose(x, perm=[0,3,1,2])
        self.kernel = tf.transpose(self.kernel, perm=[3,2,0,1])
        x = tf.signal.rfft2d(x, [shape, shape])
        self.kernel = tf.signal.rfft2d(self.kernel, [shape, shape])
        x = tf.einsum('imkl,jmkl->ijkl', x, self.kernel)
        x = tf.signal.irfft2d(x, [shape, shape])
        x = tf.transpose(x, perm=[0,2,3,1])
        x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, self.bias)[:,crop_size:-1*crop_size, crop_size:-1*crop_size, :]
        x = tf.nn.elu(x)
        return x
```

When I build the model, it shows trainable parameters only for the bias term, not for the kernels.

```
m = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
m.add(FConv2D(32, input_shape=(32,32,3)))
m.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_37"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
f_conv2d_88 (FConv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 32)        32        
=================================================================
Total params: 32
Trainable params: 32
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The problem seems to be in `call(self, x)`, because if I replace the Fourier convolution operation with a call to `tf.nn.conv2d`, the expected number of parameters is listed (3*3*3*32+32=896).

I've confirmed that the parameters are not trainable by eliminating the bias term, and calling `model.fit`, which does not run because there are no parameters to train.

What am I missing? Is Keras not able to have these complex operations inside a custom layer?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in how I was renaming variables. I set `self.kernel` to be the transformed variable, so when I instead used a different variable `W` for all operations in the transform, the parameters were listed as expected.

For reference, the code listed below is a drop in replacement for a Conv2D layer.

```
class FConv2D(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, no_of_kernels, kernel_shape, **kwargs):
        self.no_of_kernels = no_of_kernels
        self.kernel_shape = kernel_shape
        super(FConv2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=self.kernel_shape + (input_shape[-1], self.no_of_kernels),
                             initializer='random_normal',
                             trainable=True)
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.no_of_kernels,),
                             initializer='random_normal',
                             trainable=True)
        super(FConv2D, self).build(input_shape)


    def call(self, x):
        crop_size = self.kernel.get_shape().as_list()[0] // 2
        shape = x.get_shape().as_list()[1] + self.kernel.get_shape().as_list()[0] - 1
        X = tf.transpose(x, perm=[0,3,1,2])
        W = tf.transpose(self.kernel, perm=[3,2,0,1])
        X = tf.signal.rfft2d(X, [shape, shape])
        W = tf.signal.rfft2d(W, [shape, shape])
        X = tf.einsum('imkl,jmkl->ijkl', X, W)
        output = tf.signal.irfft2d(X, [shape, shape])
        output = tf.transpose(output, perm=[0,2,3,1])
        output = tf.nn.bias_add(output, self.bias)[:,crop_size:-1*crop_size, crop_size:-1*crop_size, :]
        return output
```

Use `FConv2D(32, (3,3), input_shape=(32,32,3))` for tf.keras.layers.Conv2D replacement.